# What is this metal piece behind the brake rotor?

Tags: toyota, brake-rotor, tacoma

As you can see from the image it's rusted quite badly and today I was able to rip a good chunk off. I've included an image of the opposite rotor which, while still rusted, has the whole piece intact.

Obviously a bit worried that the piece is in some way integral to the braking system.

If it's any help the vehicle is a 2003 Toyota Tacoma SR5.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is integral with the brake system, but it really does nothing for braking. **It's just a dust shield**. There's no emergency with replacing it, but should be replaced to help protect your rotors from dirt/debris.

Comment: Got it, exactly what I needed to know, thanks @pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 !